# How to use different Enum types to an object for building GUI scrollist with unique values

Tags: java, enums

Looked at a lot of postings associated with passing different Enum types to a method but do not believe my specific situation/issue was resolved.

Following is my established Enum Type class (modified to hide classified information):

```
public class ProjectA_Enums{
    private ProjectA_Enums(){
    }

    public enum TableA_Filter_Sort_Options{
        TIMESTAMP     ("TIMESTAMP", "tbla_timestamp"),
        USER          ("USER",      "tbla_user"),
        SHARE         ("SHARE",     "tbla_share"),
        CONDITION     ("CONDITION", "tbla_condition",
        TERMINAL      ("TERMINAL",  "tbla_terminal");

        private final String filter_name;
        private final String database_column_name;

        private TableA_Filter_Sort_Options(String filter_name,
                                           String database_column_name){
            this.filter_name = filter_name;
            this.database_column_name = database_column_name;
        }

        public String getFilter_name(){
            return filter_name;
        }

        public String getDatabase_column_name(){
            return database_column_name;
        }
    }

    public enum TableB_Filter_Sort_Options{
        TIMESTAMP     ("TIMESTAMP",      "tblb_timestamp"),
        ERROR_CODE    ("ERROR CODE",     "tblb_errcode"),
        ERROR_MESSAGE ("ERROR MESSAGE",  "tblb_errmsg");

        private final String filter_name;
        private final String database_column_name;

        private TableA_Filter_Sort_Options(String filter_name,
                                           String database_column_name){
            this.filter_name = filter_name;
            this.database_column_name = database_column_name;
        }

        public String getFilter_name(){
            return filter_name;
        }

        public String getDatabase_column_name(){
            return database_column_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Now here is the situation :

I want to call the class `FilterSortDialogDisplay` and pass either Enum type `TableA_Filter_Sort_Options` or `TableB_Filter_Sort_Options` to build and display a dialog GUI showing the applicable filters in a scroll pane.

This class would allow the user to select the applicable filters to perform a database query on and the desired sort order.

For Enum type `TableA_Filter_Sort_Options` the displayed filters would be TIMESTAMP, USER, SHARE, CONDITION, TERMINAL and for `TableB_Filter_Sort_Options` the displayed filters would be TIMESTAMP, ERROR CODE, ERROR MESSAGE.

The second attribute associated with each Enum type value is associated database table column to use in the resulting database query SQL. I saw in another post that one must define the input parameter of the receiving method as Class.  Due to a lack of Java knowledge I am not sure how to write the code to use the passed in Enum type.

Since I have set up both Enum types with the same exact attributes and methods, I was hoping to be able to cast an attribute in the `FilterSortDialogDisplay` class to the appropriate Enum type and just call these methods.

Hopefully Enum types are the correct construct to be used to perform the defined functionality, because there will be additional Enum types with different number and filter values for which the Filter Sort Dialog needs to be generated and displayed without the need for redundant code based on the Enum type.

Thanks ahead of time for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Holy wall of text. Your question should be specific enough that you only need a couple of lines to ask it. If you think people really need that much background info perhaps you should narrow down the question or distill down what the actual question is.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you not use enums for this. From your description it sounds as though you want to pass an object that contains enough information for the dialog to display filter information and generate the query. I would suggest you define an `interface` and then create implementations for your various tables.

A solution might look something like:

```
public interface FilterSortOption {
    Stream<Criteria> getFilterCriteria();
    String generateQuery(Map<Criteria, Value> values);
}

void showDialogAndRunQuery(FilterSortOption option) {
    ....
}
```

Then you can define several implementations of this. If they share code (as they are likely to) then that code could go into a separate class that each of the implementation delegate to. It's *possible* that that delegate class might use an enum to contain column and criteria information. I can provide pointers on how to do that if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not articulated very concisely.  I admit that after all that, I'm not certain what help it is that you need.  I would say that if your filter options are a fixed set of constants that are known at compile time, then using enums is a good practice.

> Since I have set up both Enum types with the same exact attributes and
>   methods, I was hoping to be able to cast an attribute in the
>   FilterSortDialogDisplay class to the appropriate Enum type and just
>   call these methods.

I am going to assume that what you want to do is call a method that takes, as an argument, a parameter that can be the member of a family of enum types.  Is this accurate?

There is a pattern that can be used to address this situation, the extensible enum pattern.  In this pattern, each enum class in your family of enums implements a common interface.  For example:

```
public enum TableA_FilterSortOptions implements FilterOptions {
  :
  :
}

public enum TableB_FilterSortOptions implements FilterOptions {
  :
  :
}

public interface FilterOptions { ... }
```

Here, all of the enum classes in your family share a common type, `FilterOptions`.  If you define your filtering methods to accept a parameter of type `FilterOptions`, you can pass any constant from any of your implementing enum classes to those methods.

The restriction here is that the interface must describe all the functionality of your enum classes and each enum class must implement that functionality.  When you pass an enum constant using its interface type, inside the method to which the constant was passed, the constant will "lose" its status as an enum constant, so only the interface methods will be available.

So what can you do if you need your enum constants to function as enums within the method bodies to which they are passed using the `FilterOptions` type (for example, you wanted to be able to add the constants to an EnumSet in your filtering method)?  There is a solution.  You can define generic methods that employ an intersection type.  For example:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E> & FilterOptions> void applyFilter(E option) {
  :
  :
}
```

This method is defined to accept a single argument that must be an enum constant *and* which must come from an enum class that implements the `FilterOptions` type.  Inside the body of this method, the `E` type can be added to an instance of `EnumSet<E>` and all the methods of `FilterOptions` will also be available.